# How to name return types in F#?

Tags: f#

With the following function:

```
let Calc =
    // do something
    if something
        (false, 0)
    else
        (true, some value)
```

how can I define name the output fields?

in C# I could do:

```
(bool Success, int Value) Calc()....
```

so then when I get my result, I can access the Success and Value fields by name; how can I do the same in F#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can name the fields of your tuple by binding to them like so

```ml
let Calc () =
    // do something
    if something
        (false, 0)
    else
        (true, some value)

let (success, value) = Calc ()
```

you don't have to give names to the tuple fields in the definition of `Calc` itself, you can do so at the places that use `Calc`.  If you'd prefer to give the results names, consider creating record type to contain that:

```ml
type CalcData = { success: bool; value: int }

let Calc () = 
  if something then { success = false; value = 0 }
  else { success = true, value = 123 }

let {success = success; value = value} = Calc ()
```

but it looks like your `Calc` can either return nothing or some result, which is what the `Option` type was made for:

```ml
let calc () = if something then None else Some 123

match calc () with
| None -> // if calc returned no value then do ....
| Some value -> // if calc returned a value then do ...
```

Comment: looks like I need to read about record types! just starting in F#, thanks!

Comment: You have lots of fun ahead, @Thomas (pun intended) 
One thing to note from Chesters answere is that F# functions are lower/camel case by convention. Also "something" should probably be a parameter which would make calc a pure function.